# Segmentation Fault Mac - C Code

Tags: c, fault

When compiling the code with gcc and running the executable the terminal says `Segmentation fault: 11`. Did anybody experience such a behavior before?

```
#include "stdio.h"
const int N=300;
int main(){
  FILE * infile, * outfile;
  int i, target, b[N];
  infile=fopen("b.data","r");
  outfile=fopen("found.data","w");
  fscanf(infile, "%d", & target);
  for (i=0; i<N;i++){
    fscanf(infile, "%d", & b[i]);
  }
  for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    if (b[i]==target){
      fprintf(outfile, "%d\n", i+1);}
  }
  return 0;}
```

Comment: you might want to check if `fopen` succeded before using the pointer it might be `NULL`.

Comment: Simply use a debugger and check *when* that segfault occurs, then check the variable values up to that point and you'll see why it happens. And yes, it's probably because you just ignore checking whether your calls succeeded. But how can anyone know if you didn't explain where the exe is running, where those files are, etc.?

Comment: You should check the return of fscanf. Under normal circumstances, it should be 1.  If it is EOF you should break out of the loop and save the value of i to use as the upper bound in the second loop.

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys - really appreciate that! However I could not figure out the mistake. A colleague can run the code and when writing a cpp counterpart with the same expression everything runs perfect. b.data is a file with numbers. This is actually is going to be a parallel search algorithm which will be extended with mpi.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that the above comment is correct. This is happening because it is failing to open one of your files. I got this to work on my system without issue. I would check to make sure that you typed b.data correctly when creating the file and I would also check the file permissions to make sure that you are able to read b.data and write to found.data and to the directory that you are working in.

Also there should be a semicolon after b[N] on line 5 but you must have that in your actual file or else it would not even compile.

Comment: b.data is written correctly in my folder and I forgot to add the semicolon here but got it in my code. Not sure what is failing here if it worked for you.